# Workflow loop - annual reminder

Tags: 2013, workflow, loop

I'm trying to set up a reminder for users to review their documents annually. Using SharePoint 2013.

The basic idea is that if a document is uploaded on the 18th of January, then every year on the 18th of January the user who created the document is sent a reminder to review the document.

I've added the additional columns:

- *Last Reviewed* which is set to today's date on creation and
- *Reminder Date* which calculates *Last Reviewed* plus 1 year

Then on creation of the item we start a workflow

```
Pause until 'Current Item:Reminder Date'
then Email 'Current Item:Createdby'
then Update item in 'Current Item'
```

The update item sets *Last Reviewed* to the current date, this will then recalculate the *Reminder Date* to the current date plus 1 year.

This works fine, however I need the workflow to start again after the reminder has been sent - so that it will wait until the next reminder date and re-send.

While I can set the workflow to restart after the item has been edited, there is a chance that the user will review the document but not need to make any changes so the item won't be edited and the workflow won't be restarted.

I'd appreciate any light that can be shed on this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use information management policies for this. Just enable information management policy for retention on that calendar/list, add reminder date + 0 days, start workflow, and remove the first line of that workflow logic, save and publish it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  workflow email notification and Document Expiration Policy to reach your requirement.

1. Create a workflow and attach it to the document library, set workflow starting manually, choose Send an Email in the "Actions" and put the content (e.g. library link /document link) as your requirement in the Email body to alert the owner.
2. Then go to Document Library Settings > information management policy settings, select define a policy, in the Expiration section check "Enable Expiration", set property “A time period based on the item’s properties” to Created + 1 years and set "Start this workflow" to workflow.